# What's the difference between % and %% for comments?

Tags: matlab, comments

The MATLAB editor automatically highlights all content after `%%` comments, and text after `%%` in the same line are turned bold. But what's the essential difference here? Why do people sometimes use `%%` instead of `%`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From a syntax point of view, they are both comments.

In the Matlab editor, Matlab parses `%%` delimited blocks as "sections" which you can run as a unit independent of running the whole script.

Comment: Then what is the identifier for each 'section'? I mean, how to I tell matlab to run a particular section?

Comment: My editor has a "Run section" button next to the "Run" button in the menu bar which is absent in older Matlab versions. The editor highlights the current section your cursor is in, and that would be the section it will execute when you "Run section"

Comment: @OneZero At my ancient version (2008), you can do Alt+Enter for running the current "section". (current section is highlighted). For recent versions i don't know if it still available.

Comment: Sorry, it's Ctrl+Enter. And- for new section you need `"%% "`, with space after the `%%`. If you'll write `%%Section B`, it will not open a new section.

Answer (score 10):

One percent sign (`%`) is used for commenting lines.

Two percent signs (`%%`) have a different purpose: they are used for dividing your code into [sections](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html), which can be run independently. This allows easier debugging.

Answer (score 6):

I really like the double percent sign (`%%`) and use as far as possible for the following reasons:

1. Creates a **cell block** which could be **run separately** from the whole code (*Ctrl* + *Enter*).
2. As mentioned in [sections](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html), it improves the **readability** of the file and appears as a heading if you [**publish**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) your code. It increases concentration by creating a **yellow background** and you can focus more on the part that you are working on.
3. You can fold the code in *cell blocks*. (First you should enable code folding of cell blocks in *Preferences >> Editor/Debugger >> Code Folding >> Sections*). This is useful specially in large *mfiles*.
4. If you care about keeping a **clean *Command History*** running the codes in cell blocks (*Ctrl* + *Enter*) does not leave any trace in *Command History* , unlike the *Evaluate Selection* (*F9*) which evaluates the selected (highlighted) code and holds the executed code in *Command History*.

Hope it helps.